# Under what parameters / code / publish actions / permissions can an app create Facebook Events?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

*There is no way to create an event via the API as of Graph API v2.0.*

I totally understand that this is not allowed - "in no way". So, how are some company apps pushing / creating Facebook Events?

This is form a help article form 5/12 explain how to use Facebook Integration to publish an Eventbrite Event to Facebook as an Event.

http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/en_us/portal/articles/428611

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it on Eventbrite? Because they may just still be at v1.0 with their App, and it will stop working for them after they got upgraded to v2.0 - which will happen for sure in the next few weeks. Facebook did not upgrade everyone at the same time.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to believe that Eventbrite simply pays Facebook a lot of money to have privileged access to features that the rest of us do not get access to.  They probably aren't using Graph API at all..

Comment: who knows, i just don´t believe it. even if they do, you will definitely not be able to create events.